# $T:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n $ be an isometry , is $T$ surjective?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry

Let $T:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n $ be an isometry and $T(0)=0$ , then $T$ is linear and $T(B[0,1])\subseteq B[0,1]$ so $T:B[0,1]\to B[0,1]$ is an 
isometry and since $B[0,1]$ is compact so $T|_{B[0,1]}$ is surjective ( It is well known that if $K$ is a compact metric space and $f:K \to K$ is isometry then $f$ is surjective ) i.e. $T(B[0,1])=B[0,1]$ , so then $T$ is surjective . My question is , suppose we drop the assumption $T(0)=0$ , Is $T$ still surjective ?

Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the difficulty in taking  the compact $K$ any closed ball $\overline{B_R(0)}$ rather than just only $\overline{B_1(0)} $ as you did? (Assuming that the theorem you cite is correct)

Comment: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/LectureNotes/LectureNotes2U.pdf Might be of your interest.

Comment: In the first sentence, you have "and $T(0)$". Do you mean "and $T(0)=0$"?

Comment: @robjohn : yes , thank you for pointing out :)

Comment: Related (for the claim "then $T$ is linear"): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194538

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know that $T$ is linear if $T(0) = 0$.  *However*, consider the maps
$$
S(x) = T(x) - T(0)\\
R(x) = x + T(0)
$$
Then clearly both $R$ and $S$ are isometries with $T = R \circ S$.  However, since $S(0) = 0$, $S$ is linear, and by the rank-nullity theorem any injective linear map is surjective.  Moreover, the translation $R$ is clearly surjective.  Thus, the composition $R \circ S = T$ must also be surjective.

So, $T$ is indeed necessarily surjective.

Comment: Not every linear mao is surjective , but any linear injective map is surjective and indeed , any  isometry is injective

Comment: @user228169 yes, that's what I meant. Hence "rank nullity theorem"

Comment: very clever solution , it doesn't even need to use the fact about compact metric spaces