# If $\Vert Tx-Ty \Vert = \Vert x-y \Vert$ for all $x,y \in X$ and $T(0)=0$ then T is a linear aplication.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Problem: Lets $X$ and $Y$ normed vector spaces $T:X\rightarrow Y$ a aplication such that $\Vert Tx-Ty \Vert = \Vert x-y \Vert$ for all $x,y \in X$ and $T(0)=0$ then T is a linear aplication.

My attempt: If I evaluate in $0$:
$$\Vert Tx \Vert = \Vert x\Vert \quad \mbox{for all $x \in X$}$$
Then,
$$\Vert T(x+y) \Vert = \Vert x+y\Vert \leq \Vert x\Vert + \Vert y\Vert = \Vert Tx\Vert+\Vert Ty\Vert$$
But, I do not know how to continue.

Comment: Done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194538/showing-that-an-isometry-on-the-euclidean-plane-fixing-the-origin-is-linear?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: In the linked questions, the space is assumed to be Euclidean, i.e., provided with an inner product structure. Here, the spaces are just normed.

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62380/when-do-0-preserving-isometries-have-to-be-linear

Comment: A short concise paper related to what you're asking is given [here](http://www.helsinki.fi/~jvaisala/mazurulam.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true in general: Set $X=\mathbb R$ and $Y:=\mathbb R^2$ with maximum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.

Define $T$ by
$$
T(x) := (x, \ |x|).
$$
Then $T(0)=0$ and
$$
\|T(x)-T(y)\| = \max( |x-y|,  \big| |x|-|y| \big|) = |x-y|
$$
due to $ \big||x|-|y| \big|\le |x-y|$.

The claim is true if $T$ is assumed to be bijective,
see the answer to this question:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62380/when-do-0-preserving-isometries-have-to-be-linear

In an inner product setting the answer is affirmative, see [Showing that an Isometry on the Euclidean Plane fixing the origin is Linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194538/showing-that-an-isometry-on-the-euclidean-plane-fixing-the-origin-is-linear)